# auth0 authentification and custom database is not working

Tags: mysql, angularjs, database, auth0

I'm using auth0 as my authentification services into my angularjs project, i have made mysql accessible by any public  ip and i tested it with different PCs , but sill get the timeout error:

"[SandboxTimeoutError] Script execution did not complete within 20 seconds. Are you calling the callback function?"

I also tried ngrok but it doesn't work since i'm using windows 10 , so does any one knows what is I'm missing exactly , and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to access the MySQL database outside of the sandbox?

Also - as per the message error - are you calling the callback function?

Have you tried using webtask to debug and see any additional errors that could be occurring?

If you don't mind sharing a small snippet of your code I would be happy to take a look and see if anything is missing.

Thanks,
Ado

Comment: here's my code :
function create (user, callback) {
  var connection = mysql({
    host     : configuration.host,
    user     : configuration.user,
    password : '',
    database : configuration.database
  });

  connection.connect();

  var query = "INSERT INTO users SET ?";

  var insert = { 
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10),
    email:    user.email
  };

  connection.query(query, insert, function (err, results) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    if (results.length === 0) return callback();
    
    callback(null);
  
  });

}

Comment: I use the original code provided by auth0 , I just changed the host to my ip adresse.

Comment: I notice you're not setting a password for your database in that sample? Is your database password protected?